# Is flux the accumulation of divergence, and circulation the accumulation of curl?

Tags: vector-analysis, intuition, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

What is the simple relationship expressed *verbally* between flux, circulation, div, and curl, as captured by Green's, Stokes', and Gauss' Theorems? Below is what I've been able to assemble: Can you confirm or improve it?

Given a vector field, we can measure its *instantaneous rate of change* in multiple ways, the two most important being div (a scalar) and curl (a vector).  Each of these can be accumulated in a region.  These theorems shows that this accumulation *equals a property of the region's boundary*:

**Flux** (through a boundary) **equals the accumulation of divergence** (in the bounded region).

**Circulation** (around a boundary) **equals the accumulation of curl** (in the bounded region).

More fundamentally, neither flux nor circulation is limited to boundaries: they, or their equivalents, can be measured in non-closed curves as well.  Only in that case, there is no relationship to any accumulation.  That is: Flux can be measured across a simple curve or surface that is not closed.  But this has no relationship to divergence.

Likewise, a quantity equivalent to circulation can be measured through a simple curve or surface that is not closed, but if the curve isn't closed, it's called a line integral or work integral (or, for a surface, a surface integral).  Neither has any relationship to curl.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by "verbally" (maybe without explicit equations?), but all of the theorems you mention are special cases of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thank you.  I haven't been able to follow the Generalized Stokes theorem, as I'm not familiar with differential forms (and the sources I've tried to read have been very intimidating).  Without knowing the Generalized Stokes theorem, are the OP's statements correct?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Roughly speaking, the theorem says that the integral of a quantity over the boundary of a bounded region is the same as the integral over the region itself of the derivative of that quantity. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is also a special case of this theorem!

Comment: There are also closed curves/surfaces that do not bound (if, say, there are holes in the ambient space).